# Gradle - Handling external resources

Tags: groovy, classpath, gradle

I am trying to move a simple Groovy project to Gradle. I was mostly able to configure the project, but I do not know how to deal with external resources.

Basically, my application needs to access a configuration file in JSON. Before moving to Gradle, I used to pass the location of this JSON file on the command line. I had made a simple bash script to call the main class with the correct path for the resource.

With Gradle if I understand correctly, I should be able to move this file into `src/main/resources/` and have it available somehow from the Groovy classes. Question is: how?

**EDIT**

If I understand correctly, the resource should end in the JAR that gets built. My dir structure is like

```
src
  main
    groovy
      orgName
        packageName
          source.groovy
    resources
      orgName
        packageName
          config.json
```

But I do not see the resource inside the packageName.jar that is generated in the `build` directory

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I knocked up a quick example...  Given this directory structure:

```
.
|-- src
|    |-- main
|         |-- groovy
|         |    \-- org
|         |         |-- Test.groovy
|         \-- resources
|              \-- config.json
\-- build.gradle
```

Where `Test.groovy` is:

```
package org

import groovy.json.*

public class Test {
  static main( args ) {
    def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
    def config = slurper.parseText( Test.class.getResource( '/config.json' ).text )
    println "Args were $args, config is $config"
  }
}
```

`config.json` is:

```
{
  "data": true
}
```

and `build.gradle` is:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  groovy 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.0.0'
}

task runTest ( dependsOn: 'classes', type: JavaExec ) {
  main = 'org.Test'
  classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
  args 'ARG1'
}
```

You should just be able to run `gradle runTest` and it should just work...

Comment: Thank you, you are my life saver! :-)

Comment: Still, I have one doubt. Now everything works, but the resource does not end up into the JAR. Shouldn't ii?

Comment: run `gradle build` (to build the jar) then it should be there.  In this example, `jar -tf build/libs/project.jar` shows `config.json` as being in the root of the jar file...

Answer (score 2):

Gradle doesn't mandate that you treat the file as a resource. It's just a Java/JVM best practice. If you do so, you'll have to access the file via a class loader. See [Locating resources in Java](http://littletutorials.com/2008/03/26/locating-resources-in-java/) for an explanation. Note that this is unrelated to Gradle, except that Gradle will add files under `src/main/resources` to the Jar that gets built.

Comment: Well, my problem is that I do not see the resource in the JAR. I will edit the question to show my directory structure

Comment: Have you checked if the file is contained in the Jar? You can either unzip the Jar or use `jar -tf path/to/jar/file` to list its contents. The most common error is using the wrong resource name when dealing with the class (loader) API.

Comment: Resource link dead